# Как ограничить область действия поворота камеры от Cinemachine в Unity?

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android, unity3d-ui

У меня есть игрок-шарик с FreeLook камерой от Cinemachine. Я создал Canvas дабы разместить HUD. В итоге при нажатии на джойстик (и другие объекты UI) срабатывает и поворот камеры от Cinemachine и сам джойстик одновременно. И это создает БАГ. Можно ли ограничить пространство срабатывания поворота камеры от Cinemachine и если да, то как?
[image]